# Why were most of the characters' names changed in the dubs?

Tags: captain-tsubasa

In the anime [Captain Tsubasa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Tsubasa) (I don't know if this is the most well-known name, since I knew it as "Campeões: Oliver e Benji", its Portuguese dub name), most of the characters' names were changed when the series was dubbed.

For instances, in the Portuguese dub, these are some of the names that were changed:
    **Ozora** Tsubasa - **Oliver** Tsubasa
    **Genzo Wakabayashi** - **Benji Price**
    **Ryo** Ishizaki - **Bruce** Ishizaki
    **Taro** Misaki - **Toby** Misaki (or **Tobi** Misaki)
    **Kojirou Hyuga** - **Mark Landers**
    **Jun Misugi** - **Julian Ross**
    **Hikaru** Matsuyama - **Philip** Matsuyama
    Shingo **Aoi** - Shingo **Au**
    **Nakazawa** Sanae - **Patrícia** Sanae (usually called Patty)

From what I know, almost every dub (if not every single one) changed some names when the series was dubbed. I also know that some of the changes were different from dub to dub.

Were these changes something that happened because every dub 'team' decided to change the names?
Or was it something that happened in the first dub, and that all the other dubs decided to follow (possibly because they were dubbed from the dub, instead of the original), unaware of the changed names?

Also, provided that the list is not too extensive, what names were changed in what dubs?

Answer (score 1):

Captain Tsubasa IS a very popular anime that was said to inspire a sense of sportsmanship in children. Anime is well known for its influence on the audience.

When it was dubbed, (in Hindi (Indian)) the names were not changed since they could very easily be distinguished in my language as something foreign. The pronunciation varied drastically though.
I suppose the names were changed to make things easier as it was aimed at a younger audience who might have trouble remembering names they don't often hear in their regions. 
If I recall clearly, there weren't any changes in the English dub either.

It also depends on the dub team. If I were young and I saw complicated names in a cartoon (not familiar with anime then) and others, I might as well prefer something else without giving it much time or chance.